# Shiv'a Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-seven?

### ?שבעה ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 297.

I'm pretty sure there's no lazy gematria available for this one.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-sixentries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 297 of Yoreh De'ah (in Shulchan Aruch) is unusual in that there are two of them, [one](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=251) covering the laws of planting mixtures (kilayim) of plants other than grapevines, the [other](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=254) about the laws of crossbreeding animals.

Comment: I always wondered why this is...

Comment: @DoubleAA: in Tur, kilai zera'im and kilai hakerem are combined into one section (296). Maybe the Mechaber figured that this combination would make far too long a chapter - in Shulchan Aruch, those two sections are, respectively, 69 and 40 paragraphs. (And indeed, in the first edition of Yoreh Deah (Venice, 1567), kilai zeraim is [numbered](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45234&st=&pgnum=192) 296 (repeating the number from kilai hakerem) rather than 297 - i.e., he split the Tur's 296 into two parts.)