# Kilaim of inedible plants?

Tags: halacha, kilayim-forbidden-mixture, home-house

Does Kilaim apply to plants with no edible parts, like grass?  Do homeowners need to be concerned with how they landscape if they have only plants with no edible parts in their plans?

Comment: Just to be clear you are talking about kil'ei zeraim and not kil'ei hakerem?

Comment: @DoubleAA, wouldn't Kilei HaKerem inherently be fruit-bearing?

Comment: The Kerem part, but perhaps you are asking about the other element. (The answer regarding non-edible plants is the same AFAIK). You can ask about both if you want, I just think it's worth clarifying because people often conflate the two.

Comment: @DoubleAA, you mean if you mix Kerem with non-fruit plants? I was not asking that.  I was asking non-fruit with different non-fruit.  You're saying fruit (even Kerem) with non-fruit is ok?

Comment: I believe so, yes. I'm pretty sure not-fruit is like not-there.

Comment: SethJ, to clarify: are you asking about plants that bear no edible fruit (like wheat), plants that bear no fruit (like California nutmeg), or (as @DoubleAA seems to be assuming) plants that bear no edible part (like elm)?

Comment: @msh210 not edible whatsoever. If you think I should broaden to ask what is and is not included, I can.

Comment: @msh210, you don't think this will open more questions about what is meant by "inedible"?

Comment: Possibly, though it actually seems pretty clear IMO. But I really think the "non-fruit" wording is not the way to go, as that would include potato and wheat. Do you disagree?

Comment: @msh210 I disagree because they are "fruiting" plants. "Inedible", to me, implies the bark of the tree or something poisonous, not merely green, leafy stuff with no fruit.  And yew bushes? You edited in an example I've never heard of.

Comment: @SethJ, obviously tweak or roll back at will. Meanwhile I'll try to tweak further: see if you like it.

Answer (score 5):

The Rambam writes ([Hilchot Kilaim 1:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7101.htm#3))

> אין אסור משום כלאי זרעים, אלא זרעים הראויין למאכל אדם; אבל עשבים המרים, וכיוצא בהן מן העיקרין שאינן ראויין אלא לרפואה, וכיוצא בהן--אין בהן משום כלאי זרעים.‏
>   The prohibition of Kilei Zeraim (mixed seeds) only applies to seeds [of plants] which are human food. Bitter herbs and other herbs which are only used for healing or some other purpose are not included in the prohibition of Kilei Zeraim.

The Shulchan Aruch rules as such almost word for word in YD 297[a](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15866/759):3.